# Highcharts gauge style

Tags: highcharts, gauge

I would want realize a gauge with highcharts similar this pics, ayone can help me? In particular with this dials style.

[image]

I found a start example on this jsfidlle

> jsfiddle.net/6r654hr9/4/

Comment: Questions asking to completely solve a particular problem or task are **not** suitable for SO. You're expected to find your own solution first - and then, if you get stuck with a specific problem, you're very welcome to ask it on SO. Please review the [SO help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: ok, thanks. I'll do better in my next post, delete this post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do to achieve the wanted result (starting from your jsfiddle demo) is set the `pivot.radius` to higher value and positioning the `dataLabel` properly.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jp7znmce/

```
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    zIndex: 20,
    y: -17,
    style: {
      fontSize: '20px'
    },
    borderWidth: 0
  }
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.gauge.pivot.radius

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.gauge.dataLabels.style